# How create element div top vertical with border radius and background linear gradient

Tags: html, css, border-radius

I need to create a div with the top left and right border with different heights, with a radius of 50px at each top end respectively, plus a linear gradient background color.

Do you know if it is possible to create it with CSS and HTML?

Thanks for your comments.

It should look like below:

[image]

Comment: People will have more motivation to help you if you show them that you made at least some effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need 2 `div`s for this, with 1 nested in the other.

Rotate the child element using `transform: rotate(deg)` and hide the overflowing sides by applying `overflow:hidden` to the parent.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #E6E6E6;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 8px;
}

.child {
  height: 222px;
  width: 217px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  background: linear-gradient( 0deg, #FFFFFF, #E9F3FF);
  border-radius: 25px 25px 0px 0px;
  transform: rotate( -6deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with a lot of manipulation (building on the other answer but closer to the example):

We need three divs. The outer one is the wrapper (invisible). The second one is the one with "different heights" and a gradient, which is rotated to give the "different heights" illusion. Finally, we have another div that's almost the same as the second one but fills in the empty space caused by the rotation of the second one.

```css
#wrapper {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#f {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150%;
  top: 20px;
  left: 18px;
  background: linear-gradient( 0deg, #FFFFFF, #E9F3FF);
  border-radius: 10px 25px 0 0;
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}
#g {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150%;
  top: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient( 0deg, #FFFFFF, #E9F3FF);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="f"></div>
  <div id="g"></div>
</div>
```